# Docusign api php add signer on the fly to template

Tags: php, docusignapi

when i add new recepient and sent the document in template using below code

```
$templateRole = new  \DocuSign\eSign\Model\TemplateRole();
$templateRole->setEmail("user@email.com");
$templateRole->setName("User Name");
$templateRole->setRoleName("Admin");
```

I use [Docusign Php Client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client), you can find the whole code below I used for this on that page.

Here it send the email containing document to user@email.com, but user@email.com's user is not able to sign that document.

I've also added the dynamic text to the document in the template.Added one signer recipient to template (because i was not able to add the dynamic labels without it), **this user get all the emails** even i don't specify him on the above code.

I want something like to send a document in template to different recepients (like user1@gmail.com, user2@gmail.com etc) one at a time (they may or may not have docusign account, though is it possible if they have docusign account?)

I am doing this since 4 days, not finding anything about proceeding furthur, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have read some of the documentation. As far as I can see you should do the following:

```
//first signer
$templateRole1 = new  \DocuSign\eSign\Model\TemplateRole();
$templateRole1->setEmail("user1@email.com");
$templateRole1->setName("User1 Name");
$templateRole1->setRoleName("Admin");

//second singer
$templateRole2 = new  \DocuSign\eSign\Model\TemplateRole();
$templateRole2->setEmail("user2@email.com");
$templateRole2->setName("User2 Name");
$templateRole2->setRoleName("Admin");
```

And then in the envelop:

```
$envelop_definition->setTemplateRoles(array($templateRole1, $templateRole2));
```